# save json block of code into nested model ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, jbuilder

I get a hash of results from `get_connection` with koala gem which looks something like this

```
=> [{"album"=>{"created_time"=>"2011-05-07T23:06:33+0000", "name"=>"Timeline Photos", 
"id"=>"10150170707957371"}, "images"=>[{"height"=>1150, "source"=>"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/24173690_10155086191327371_1463889654041392146_o.jpg?oh=8adec503c6066dc20d1be5d71262a03e&oe=5AFEED4A",
"width"=>2048}, {"album"=>{"created_time"=>"2011-05-07T23:06:33+0000", "name"=>"Timeline Photos", 
"id"=>"10150170707957371"}, "images"=>[{"height"=>1188, "source"=>"https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t31.0-8/24302317_10155086179077371_4000719398736973936_o.jpg?oh=6eba399a4067b847cb38ef245e687321&oe=5AFC195A", 
"width"=>2639}]}]
```

I was looking to save photos like rails does with the params hash but realized it only creates a gallery for each photo with a `do` block .

```
def photos(user)
  photos = user.facebook.get_connection("me", "photos?fields=album,images,event,height,width,link,place&type=uploaded")
    photos.each do |photo|
      params = { gallery: {
      name: 'Facebook Pictures', pictures_attributes: [
      { fb_album_created_time: photo['album']['created_time'],
        fb_album_name: photo['album']['name'],
        fb_album_id: photo['album']['id'],
        fb_source: photo['images'][0]['source'],
        fb_height: photo['images'][0]['height'],
        fb_width: photo['images'][0]['width'],
        fb_link: photo['link'],
        fb_pic_id: photo['id'] }
        ]
      }
    }
    gallery = user.galleries.new(params[:gallery])
    gallery.save!
  end     
end
```

How can I execute my nested picture attributes so they save to one gallery. Even a gem which could help me. I was looking at the rails/jbuider gem but not sure if its easier without a gem?

Comment: Do you have `User`, `Gallery` and `Picture` models? Does `Gallery` models have many pictures and accepts nested attributes for they?

Comment: yes and everything is saving correctly. I am just looking at the jbuilder gem and it says you can extract attributes so just checking that atm.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed this with Jbuilder.

```
def to_jbuilder
  Jbuilder.new
end

def photos(u)
  json = to_jbuilder
  first_page_photos = u.facebook.get_connection("me", "photos?fields=album,images,event,height,width,link,place&type=uploaded")
  photos = json.photo first_page_photos do |photo|
    json.fb_album_created_time photo['album']['created_time']
    json.fb_album_name photo['album']['name']
    json.fb_album_id photo['album']['id']
    json.fb_source photo['images'][0]['source']
    json.fb_height photo['images'][0]['height']
    json.fb_width photo['images'][0]['width']
    json.fb_link photo['link']
    json.fb_pic_id photo['id']
  end
  params = { gallery: { name: 'Facebook Pictures', pictures_attributes: photos }}
  gallery = u.galleries.new(params[:gallery])
  gallery.save!
end
```